# Why Are My Object's Properties Being Overwritten?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code in Angular, which is an attempt to allow for multiple instances of the same Controller on the same web page.  The problem is, every time a new instance is created, it adds itself to the instance object, but erases the other properties (i.e, instances) on the instance object.  I think this is a simple javascript syntax problem unrelated to Angular, but I can't figure it out.  Any advice?

```
angular.module('mean.root').controller('ContentA1Controller', ['$scope', '$location', 'Global', 'Data', '$timeout', '$interval', 'Clients', 'Modals', '$element', function ($scope, $location, Global, Data, $timeout, $interval, Clients, Modals, $element) {

            // Defaults
            $scope.instances = { A: {}, B: {}, C: {}, D: {}, E: {}, F: {} };

            // Methods
            $scope.createNewInstance = function() {
                var instance = $($element).closest('.content-container').attr('id');
                // Add ID to content
                $($element).find('.content').attr( "id", "contentA1instance"+instance );
                Data.priceByDay(function(prices){
                    // Load Chart Data
                    $scope.instances[instance].data = [1,2,3,4,5];
                    // Log Instance Object
                    console.log($scope.instances);
```

So, when I add one instance to the controller, it works and I log:

```
$scope.instances = { A: { data: [1,2,3,4,5] }, B: {}, C: {}, D: {}, E: {}, F: {} }
```

Then when I add another instance, running the createNewInstance() method again, it will log:

```
$scope.instances = { A: {}, B: { data: [1,2,3,4,5] }, C: {}, D: {}, E: {}, F: {} }
```

Comment: Maybe it re-runs the whole controller?

Comment: You're right, of course it does, jeesh how obvious is that, now I need to redesign this compeltely..

Comment: An [AngularJS service](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services) is a great place to keep data that spans multiple `$scope`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var instance = $($element).closest('.content-container').attr('id');
....
$scope.instances[instance].data = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

it's choosing the `id` of the closest `.content-container` to the element where the controller is bound in the page.  Since you said you've used the controller twice, one of those bindings is closer to `.content-container#A` and one is closer to `.content-container#B`.  This looks like the code is "working as designed" but you may not have "designed what you meant".

Comment: Nice, articulate way of explaining what's going here.  Thank you Nate.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a different controller for each instance and keeping shared data in $rootScope, or better yet use one contoller for the whole page and having each instance operate on only one map item.